# Invalid CfStringRef plist (Array of dictionaries) iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, plist, nsmutabledictionary, cfstring

I have the following code in my file

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"plist"];
                NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


                for (id dict in array) {


                    NSLog(@"This is the id: %@" ,[dict objectForKey:@"Id"]);

                }
```

When I run this on the debugger it comes back saying 'invalid CfStringref' on the NSString *filePath line.

No matter what code I try I cannot get past this.

Any ideas?

Also the plist is a Array of dictionaries but I can't get to parse them since the code won't work

Comment: Supporting files?  That directory doesn't exist.  Is it in the documents directory, library directory, or in the bundle?

Comment: Inside of our app folder we have a directory called Supporting files. main.m is in their as well as this plist.

Comment: No, on the device, Xcode folders ***don't matter***. You could have a million bajillion folders in Xcode, but the iOS sandbox doesn't give a rat's behind about Xcode's file structure.  So, is this in the app bundle, or not?

Comment: Yes it is in the device bundle

Comment: Does `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"plist"]);` return null, or a path?

Comment: Then it doesn't exist.  Check your "Copy Bundle Resources" phase.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Thank You!
for those that have this same problem use this [Picture of settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1649.html) and click the plus button

Comment: I will put it up as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

images.plist is not in your "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase, drag it in and run again.